# How do i undo ignoring an error?

Tags: pcsx2

I was playing *Ratchet and Clank 2* on PCSX2 the other night and after clearing the Thugs-4-Less jammer the following cutscene crashed the emulator. i wrongfully hit ignore and while duplicating the issue i didn't get the error message which i would rather.

Is there a way to reset the error message so that the one i ignored is no longer ignored **without resetting the entirety of PCSX2**

Comment: Does your error show up in `C:\%PCSX2%\logs\emuLog.txt`? It looks like this file will get generated and overwritten every time you launch the program, so if you reproduce your error, does the log file contain an entry?